# PowerShell - Instantiate IPAddressCollection

Tags: .net, powershell, ip-address

I am trying to create an [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressCollection] object to store multiple [System.Net.IPAddress] objects.

Ideally I would like to achieve something similar to the following:

```
$IPAddresses = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressCollection]::new()
foreach ($target in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($file)) {
    IPAddresses .Add([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($target))
}
```

I am aware that I could go with easier implementation but for me to improve my understanding of .Net/PowerShell I would like to know how to create an instance of [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressCollection].

Thanks

Comment: Why? Just get the file content and cast each line as an `[IPAddress]` object.

Comment: I agree with @Bill_Stewart , "Why?" And further, what's your question? Is your code not working for some reason?

Comment: Why because I want to implement it this way, as simple as that, hence my question. :)

Comment: @AresOlympus `IPAddressCollection` doesn't expose a public constructor, because it's not designed to be instantiated by a user

Comment: "because I want to" - that's an XY problem. Ask about your actual problem, not the attempted solution.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart it is not, if I bothered to post it was to assess whether the implementation I had in mind was possible, not to be redirected to other people implementations of my problem.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-complicating with your type accelerators.

```
$Collection = @()
ForEach ($IP in @(Get-Content -Path $file))
{
    $Collection += @([System.Net.IPAddress]$IP)
}

$Collection
```

You end up with a `[System.Net.IPAddress[]]` type for `$Collection`

---

Further shortened by @Bill_Stewart:

`$collection = Get-Content -Path $file | ForEach-Object { [IPAddress] $_ }`

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel there is the [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressCollection] available a part of my question is how to create an instance of this class?

Comment: In PowerShell?  You don't.  There isn't a constructor available for that class. @AresOlympus

Comment: I thought that PowerShell, interact with .Net classes, methods, etc. and that therefore we could basically use [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPAddressCollection]

Comment: It does.  That doesn't mean you can write `C#` in `PowerShell` and expect it to work.  If you have a question, use this syntax to figure out if you can generate it: `[Classname] | Get-Member -Static`.  If it doesn't have a `new` Method, you can't construct it. @AresOlympus

Comment: I always cast an ip address to `[System.Version]` - that's "the PowerShell-way" I've been told.

Comment: Alright so the answer is I cannot do it that way with PowerShell, got it. I have an other issue rather than using `[System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse` I want to use the constructor, however when doing that: `$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([System.String]::new("192.168.0.105")); $ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]::New($bytes)` it does not work, any idea why?

Comment: @AresOlympus Why are you using a string constructor?  Simply using quotes (single or double) signifies it is a string.  `Parse` is a static class member, btw.  Simple use it by itself: `[IPAddress]::Parse('192.168.0.105')`.  PowerShell is a very powerful language and doesn't need to be told every little detail like C# would.

Comment: @gpunktschmitz Because `[Version]` is its own type.  It is not made to represent network addresses even if the `.ToString()` method looks the same.  It's bad to use types you don't mean to utilize.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I just find that way tidier more explicit and better practice, in my opinion. So if I can create an object using its constructor I will do it to add more verbosity to what I do. Also, for my knowledge I want to know how to do with the `new` and not the `parse`. Thanks.

Comment: @AresOlympus It has no backwards compatibility from v5 and is not *the PowerShell way*.  Sure, if whoever's looking at your code is purely a .NET programmer, they'd understand it, but that isn't usually the case with scripters.

Comment: That is the point it is aimed at developer and do not consider backward compatibility as an issue. Also for my knowledge I would like to know why it fails instantiating the IPAddress object when I am feeding the constructor with the expected parameters.

Comment: @AresOlympus You're probably using the wrong constructor: `ipaddress new(long newAddress), ipaddress new(byte[] address, long scopeid), ipaddress new(byte[] address)`

Comment: See the following example: `$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([System.String]::new("‌​192.168.0.105")); $ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]::New($bytes)`. This should work but it does not. Also a bit off topic but if you got good resources for Powershell .Net please let me know.

Comment: @AresOlympus The msdn would be a starter: [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby(v=vs.110).aspx). *The Byte array is assumed to be in network byte order with the most significant byte first in index position 0.* If you want to pass an IP **STRING**, use `Parse` or type-cast it. `[IPAddress]::new(192,168,0,105)`

Comment: @AresOlympus Correct constructor: `[IPAddress]::new(@(192,168,0,105))`

Comment: More economic - `$collection = Get-Content file | ForEach-Object { [IPAddress] $_ }`